# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'findOne') NestJS Mongoose Schema

Tags: mongoose, nestjs

I have an API made in NestJS but one of my services seems to have issues accessing my mongoose model. I've checked over everything numerous times and couldnt find anything missing, and the models are imported the same in other services and they work find. You can find the code repository here: https://github.com/codepip55/pip-api/tree/dev. It's gonna be under the dev branch and the files giving the error (see below) are under src/oauth2.

Error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'findOne')
    at Oauth2Service.getClient (C:\Users\**********\Documents\Coding\Javascript\nestjs\pip-api\src\oauth2\oauth2.service.ts:38:46)
```

Console.logging the model gives undefined as well.

The error orgiginates from:

```
 async getClient(
    clientId: string,
    clientSecret?: string,
  ): Promise<{
    client: {
      id: string;
      redirectUris: string[];
      grants: string[];
    };
  }> {
    console.log('model', await this.oauthClientModel)
    try {
      let client;
      if (!clientSecret)
        client = await this.oauthClientModel.findOne({ clientId });
      else
        client = await this.oauthClientModel.findOne({
          clientId,
          clientSecret,
        });
      if (!client) throw new NotFoundException();

      return {
        client: {
          id: client.clientId,
          redirectUris: client.redirectUris,
          grants: client.clientGrants,
        },
      };
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(1, err);
    }
  }
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

I Think you miss oauth cliend model.you should import it.

Comment: It's imported in the constructor, as you can see in the repository I provided. It is also declared in the oauth module.

Comment: Actually... I think that's correct. I haven't read your repo, but this particular error comes from a mis-reference to the model object itself. If that's `undefined` in the context, you get that error.